# Calculate datagridview rows

Tags: c#

I have made a shop app for a school project
it adds goods from goods tab to factor tab
everything is working fine but I don't know how to calculate all - total price rows to make a variable that holds the price you have to pay
EDIT: now I'm getting the error in the picture

```cs
int n = dgvfactor.Rows.Count - 1;
dgvfactor.Rows.Add();
dgvfactor.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = txtFGoodsCode.Text;
dgvfactor.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = lblgoodsname.Text;
dgvfactor.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = txtFAmount.Text;
dgvfactor.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = lblprice.Text;
int amount = int.Parse(txtFAmount.Text);
int price = int.Parse(lblprice.Text);
int total = (amount * price);
lbltotal.Text = total.ToString();
dgvfactor.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = lbltotal.Text;
var totalPrice = 0;
int rowPrice;
for (int i = 0; i < dgvfactor.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
                        
     if (int.TryParse(dgvfactor.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out rowPrice))
          {
            totalPrice += rowPrice;
          }
            }
lblpricetopay.Text = totalPrice.ToString();
```

[image]

Comment: You should create a form level field `private double totalPrice =0;`  and add individual amount to it by doing `totalPrice += amount * price;` and then assign it to the label `lbltotal.Text=totalPrice.ToString();`

Comment: it is adviseable **not** to work with the visual representation of the data, but with the underlying data itself. You should do all the calculations on the underlying data. How do you store it? How did you fill the datagridview with values?

Comment: @MongZhu i didn't link it to any database because i wouldn't be able to add goods to it
so i added Columns manually

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i added ```double totalPrice = 0; totalPrice += amount * price; lblpricetopay.Text = totalPrice.ToString();```
to it but it still shows the total price of the last good added to the factor

Comment: I am talking about the data management within your code, this is independent of the source (eg database). You should create a separate collection that holds your data, (even if you type it in manually) and use the DataGridView only for Display purpose.

Comment: `private double totalPrice = 0;` you need to declare this at form level, NOT inside the function.

Comment: I am pretty sure you may be using an older .Net version and it does not like the newer tryparse. Put `int rowPrice = 0;` BEFORE the “for” loop. Then change the try parse to: `int.TryParse(dvgFactor.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out rowPrice);`

Comment: @RoyalMello Since the picture appears to allow users to add rows, then this sounds like the last “NEW” row. Your code is not checking for this "New" row... On that row `dgvfactor.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value` will be null add this check first inside the loop… if (!dgvFactor.Rows[i].IsNewRow) { … parse the value… }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry If im mistaken here, but can't you just simply use a for-loop ?

```
var totalPrice = 0;
int rowPrice;
      
for (int i = 0; i < dgvfactor.Rows.Count; i++) {
   // Note the NOT (!) new row...
   if (!dgvfactor.Rows[i].IsNewRow) { 
     if (int.TryParse(dgvfactor.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out rowPrice))
     {
        totalPrice += rowPrice;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: @JohnG You're absolutely right, thank you. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: That should work. Just as an aside… I left out the “if” condition as it is not really needed. Even if the `int.TryParse` fails, `rowPrice` will still be a zero (0). However, the “if” certainly is more readable.

Comment: i used your code and i got 5 errors @andymeissner 
invalid expression term int
syntax error ',' expected
; expected
the name rowPrice does not exist in the current context
the name rowPrice does not exist in the current context

Comment: @RoyalMello there was a semicolon missing, try it again

Comment: now there are 4 errors @andymeissner
invalid expression term int 
invalid expression term int syntax error ',' expected
the name rowPrice does not exist in the current context 
the name rowPrice does not exist in the current context

Comment: @RoyalMello Can you post the updated code and where the errors are? Please add the additional code and errors below your existing question… DO Not add the code as a comment, add it to your original question as an edit.

Comment: @JohnG ok sry i'll do it now

Comment: The error is most probably caused by `out int rowPrice` used in `int.TryParse`. This is one of features introduced in C# 7 (inline out parameters) and most likely, RoyalMello isn't using the latest C# version in the project. To fix that, declare `rowPrice` variable one line above the `TryParse` and remove `int` after `out`.

Comment: I removed the inline declaration, now it should work for @RoyalMello

Comment: the errors are gone but now when i add a new good to the factor the program stops working with error Line:
```if (int.TryParse(dgvfactor.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out rowPrice))``` 
additional information:Object reference not set to an instance of an object. @andymeissner

Comment: @RoyalMello This sounds like the last “NEW” row. On that row `dgvfactor.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value` will be `null` add this check first inside the loop… `if (!dgvFactor.Rows[i].IsNewRow) { … parse the value… }`

Comment: this conversation here is the best example as to why one should not work with the values from the datagridview, but collect all data in a separate collection with the proper data types and calculate from it

Comment: i suck and im sorry for taking your time like that xD
how should i parse the value after the ```if (!dgvfactor.Rows[i].IsNewRow)```

Comment: @RoyalMello I've updated my answer using JohnG suggestion. Just take your time and learn ;-)